# How does calculating the probability using the cdf work in this case?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let's say we have a continous random variable $T$ and we found the following cdf for $0 < t < 1$:

$$
F(t) = (2/5)t^3 + (1/5)t^2 + (2/5)t
$$

Now we want to find $P(1/2 \le T < 1)$. My book gives the solution

$$
P(1/2 \le T < 1) = 1 - P(T < 1/2) = 1 - F(1/2)
$$

I find this a confusing question,

- Previously the book defined the cdf for a continous random variable as $F(x) = P(X \le x)$. But the solution implies that we can also assume $F(x) = P(X < x)$ ?
- Also in the book they defined $P(a \le X \le b) = F(b) - F(a)$, which doesn't work here since $F$ is not defined for $1$. Is this a "trick question" to hide that we are actually looking for $P(a \le X)$ only?

Comment: What do you think the difference is between $\Pr(X\leq x)$ and $\Pr(X<x)$?  What do you suppose $\Pr(X=x)$ is equal to for *continuous* random variables?

Comment: Yeah i think that makes sense in terms of a continuous random var, I'm just a bit puzzled that this wasn't mentioned before in the book.

Comment: And maybe to make my second question more concrete, if we need to find $P(a \le X \le b)$ but $b$ isn't in the domain of the cdf .. then it's really just $1 - P(a \le X)$ ?

Comment: @Henry you're right fixed the formatting.

Comment: The CDF of a real random variable (or should be) defined for all $\mathbb R$.  But you know it is in $[0,1]$ and a weakly increasing function, so by looking at the left and right limits of what you are told, you can see here  here that $F(x)=0$ for $x \le 0$ and $F(x)=1$ for $x \ge 1$

Comment: The points of discontinuity of the distribution function are precisely the point masses, ie points $p$ such that $\mu\{p\}\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the book skipped a step. You need to use the fact that when the cdf is a continuous function, then $P(T=t)=0$ for any $t\in \mathbb R$. This is because $$P(T=t)=\lim_{s\to t^-}P(s<T\le t)=\lim_{s\to t^-} [F(t)-F(s)]=F(t)-F(t)=0. $$
Therefore,  you can say that $$P(T<t)=P(T\le t)-P(T=t)=F(t)-0=F(t)$$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$, so $P(\tfrac12 \le T<1)=P(T<1)-P(T<\tfrac12)=F(1)-F(\tfrac12)$.

However, people will only show this step in the context of teaching a probability course, because once you get the hang of it, it is easy to automatically complete these steps in your head. You just need to be careful to not accidentally try to apply this when the cdf has jump discontinuities.

For your second issue, you asked about why you can say that $P(a\le T\le b)=F(b)-F(a)$ when the cdf is "not defined at $1$". The answer is, the domain of the cdf is **always** the entire real number line. This because, by definition, the cdf of $T$ means
$$
F(t)\stackrel{\text{def}}= P(T\le t),
$$
and this is a valid event for every real number $t$, so you can talk about its probability. In your example, the full definition of the cdf is actually this, even though they did not mention it:
$$
F(t)=
\begin{cases}
0 & t\le 0 \\
 (2/5)t^3 + (1/5)t^2 + (2/5)t & 0<t<1 \\
1 & t \ge 1
\end{cases}
$$
The remaining two cases can be inferred from the given cdf, based on the fact that $F(t)$ must be a weakly increasing function of $t$. Therefore, there is no problem with saying $P(\tfrac12 \le T<1)=F(1)-F(\frac12)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, these are some very good clarifications I was looking for.